# Trying to plot a random function but it seems that it's not quite random

Tags: python, random, statistics

I am trying to plot a random function from a textbook that looks like this:

[image]

What I did was to generate a random number between 1 to 20 for all numbers in a range.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.arange(1,20,0.2).tolist()
Random = [random.random() for x in X]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1)
axs.plot(X, Random,linestyle = 'dotted', color='r')
```

Then I plotted this But I got this:

[image]

Now I am wondering this is not quite random, We can see in some ranges that the function is increasing or decreasing, It looks like the values are not completely independent from each other.
My question is that how can I write a function that is completely random like the first picture.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: We can't tell *how* you plotted the collection, nor *what* you plotted.  It *looks* as if you made a couple of obvious errors: (1) you did a line plot instead of a scatter plot,  (2) your plot interpolates between points (or maybe you just used a dotted line).  Please repeat your tutorial to make sure that your plot choice is what you want, and that your input values are what that function call requires.  Then reduce this to a *minimal* example, give us *complete* code.

Comment: It looks like you've made a couple of glaring errors.  The first plot appears to be values vs values, while your second plot appears to be values vs sequence-index.  These are two entirely different things, so of course they look different from each other!  You also appear to have played "connect the dots" using dashed lines in the second plot, which makes it look like extended sequences up or down. The problem is that you haven't fully described your plots nor have you provided actual working code which produces those plots, so we're left to guess about what you have actually done.

Comment: Sorry about the vague question and code ... I updated the code so that you can use it and run it

Comment: Still lacking a description of what the axes are in your first plot.  An essential component of interpreting a graph or plot is to know what is being plotted.

Comment: Your results look pretty random to me – each data point (not the connections between them!) seems unrelated to the others. Can you clarify what makes you think they are not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horizontal and vertical axes are the same in your first plot, the one you said you want to reproduce, leading me to believe that it is plotting pairs of random numbers against each other.  (It actually looks like they are U(-6,6) values.)  That's what the following code does:

```python
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

randnums = [random.random() for _ in range(101)]
plt.scatter(randnums[0:100], randnums[1:101])
plt.show()
```

Results will vary from run to run, but look like this:

[image: Plot of sequential pairs of random numbers]

This plot indicates that adjacent values are equally balanced in all four quadrants of the unit square, which is a good indication that they are uncorrelated but nowhere near as good as doing rigorous testing.

It's worth mentioning that humans are notoriously bad at judging randomness.  That's why the PRNGs used in most language libraries are thoroughly vetted by a large battery of statistical tests.  See Wikipedia for details about the [Diehard tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) or the [TestU01 suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01).  Python's `random` uses [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), which has been subjected to those tests and been deemed adequate for statistical (but not cryptographic) use.  In other words, you don't need to do the testing, it's already been done.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it well with the same code.
Why don't you try running it again?
I think you have to use scattar .

```
X = np.arange(1,20,0.2).tolist()
Random = [random.random() for x in X]
plt.scatter(X,Random)
```

[image: plot of the results]

Comment: No, it's different. You use a scatter plot. However, your solution has fit the need of the question. Just need to edit your explanation.